# Custom Implementation of strcmp in C++ not Working

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am scratching my head... why is the return statement inside strcmp_iter never being called?

When I run this function, the output is simply to count from 0 to 6 and then terminate... no return statement. Very frustrating. Interestingly, if I change myString2 to "abcdefG" then everything works fine... very odd.

```
int strcmp_iter(string s1, string s2) {
  int i = 0;
  for (; ((s1.at(i) == s2.at(i)) && (i <= s1.length())); i++) {
    cout << i << endl;
  }
  return s1.at(i) - s2.at(i);
}


int main() {
  string myString1 = "abcdefg";
  string myString2 = "abcdefg";

  int count_iter = strcmp_iter(myString1, myString2);
  cout << "Iter: " << count_iter << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't pass strings by value if you are not going to copy them. Also use iterators. And prefer ++i to i++.

Comment: What makes you say that the `return` is never executed?

Comment: That exception you get when you run it with equal strings should be pretty clear.

Comment: Not the problem, but there are too many parentheses in the loop termination test. C++ isn't LISP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping beyond the bounds of the string and probably throwing an `std::out_of_range` exception. Change your condition to

```
i < s1.length()
```

and make that check *before* any calls to `std::string::at(size_type pos)`

Also, beware your function can only work if `s2` is at least as long as `s1`. You should probably be looping up to one less than `std::min(s1.length(), s2.length())`.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I see this construction, it makes me cringe:

```
 for (; ((s1.at(i) == s2.at(i)) && (i <= s1.length())); i++)
```

C-like languages always do short circuit evaluation and from left to right.  So the condition for termination—and validating that the comparison makes sense to do—should precede the comparison:

```
 int n = s1.length();
 if (s2.length() < n)
       n = s2.length();   // choose smaller length
 for (; i < n  &&  s1.at(i) == s2.at(i); i++)
```

(I have also removed unnecessary parentheses, limited the search length to the short string, and changed `<=` to `<` because of how array subscripts work.)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (; ((s1.at(i) == s2.at(i)) && (i <= s1.length())); i++) {
```

use `i < s1.length()`